# TinyMCE .filter() is not a function on mention (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, tinymce, tinymce-5

I've been trying to crack my problem for quite some time however no matter what I do I can't figure this out. Currently, following the docs from TinyMCE, this code is provided by them.

```
  /* This represents a database of users on the server */
  var userDb = {};
  userNames.map(function(fullName) {
      var name = fullName.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');
      var description = descriptions[Math.floor(descriptions.length * Math.random())];
      var image = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/' + images[Math.floor(images.length * Math.random())] + '/128.jpg';
      return {
          id: name,
          name: name,
          fullName: fullName,
          description: description,
          image: image
      };
  }).forEach(function(user) {
      userDb[user.id] = user;
  });

  /* This represents getting the complete list of users from the server with only basic details */
  var fetchUsers = function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, _reject) {
          /* simulate a server delay */
          setTimeout(function() {
              var users = Object.keys(userDb).map(function(id) {
                  return {
                      id: id,
                      name: userDb[id].name,
                  };
              });
              resolve(users);
          }, 500);
      });
  };

  /* This represents requesting all the details of a single user from the server database */
  var fetchUser = function(id) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          /* simulate a server delay */
          setTimeout(function() {
              if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(userDb, id)) {
                  resolve(userDb[id]);
              }
              reject('unknown user id "' + id + '"');
          }, 300);
      });
  };

  return {
      fetchUsers: fetchUsers,
      fetchUser: fetchUser
  };
  })();

  /* These are "local" caches of the data returned from the fake server */
  var usersRequest = null;
  var userRequest = {};

  var mentions_fetch = function(query, success) {
      /* Fetch your full user list from somewhere */
      if (usersRequest === null) {
          usersRequest = fakeServer.fetchUsers();
      }
      usersRequest.then(function(users) {
          /* query.term is the text the user typed after the '@' */
          users = users.filter(function(user) {
              return user.name.indexOf(query.term.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
          });

          users = users.slice(0, 10);

          /* Where the user object must contain the properties `id` and `name`
             but you could additionally include anything else you deem useful. */
          success(users);
      });
  };
```

When I try to change the fake server to get data from my actual server through an API route, however, I get .filter is not a function error. So I figured I would use the Object. values() method, but that doesn't return anything and the console log shows up empty.

This is my logic in my controller (I'm using Laravel btw)

```
    public function getUsers(Request $request) {
    $user = User::all();
    return $user;
}
```

The filter problem happens when I change this line :

```
      if (usersRequest === null) {
      usersRequest = fakeServer.fetchUsers();
  }
```

To my API call like this:

```
     if (usersRequest === null) {
      usersRequest = fetch('api/users/mention');
  }
```

My API response is as follows:

```
    [{id: 1, name: "John", email: "john@doe.com", email_verified_at: null,…},…]
0: {id: 1, name: "John", email: "john@doe.com", email_verified_at: null,…}
1: {id: 2, name: "Admin", email: "vi@example.com", email_verified_at: "2021-02-07 12:01:18",…}
2: {id: 3, name: "Admin2", email: "di@example", email_verified_at: "2021-02-07 12:01:46",…}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: usersRequest = fetch('api/users/mention'); I don't see your fetch function but it's probably asynchronous i.e. it doesn't return user data immediately and a callback function is needed to retrieve the data.

Comment: Hi Anurat, what you wrote is the fetch function, the api response is from the console log :) However, for some reason the filter function just doesnt work and I'm assuming it's to do with the api response being objects

Comment: okay, please show your api response using console.log or something.

Comment: I've added the images from my inspect element to the question, hope it helps

Comment: okay, but what's the value of userRequest? try console.log(userRequest) if it's null then the data doesn't return with fetch()

Comment: The value of console.log(userRequest) displays  Promise {<pending>}and when I console.log(users) in usersRequest.then(function(users) , it displays promise fulfilled

Comment: I think you are not using fetch() correctly. https://5balloons.info/example-of-vanilla-javascript-fetch-post-api-in-laravel/

Comment: Thank you Anurat, I'm reading through it currently, although I'm not sure why I'm using fetch wrongly when it's following the official documentation by TinyMCE? https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/premium/mentions/#exampleusingmentions_fetch

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! After painstakingly trying and trying, I managed to find a solution.

Wrap the tinymce script in a function, I wrapped mine in a function called function tinyMCE()

before the function, run an ajax api call

```
var usergetNames = [];
    $.ajax({
           url: '/api/users/mention',
            method: 'get',
             dataType: 'json',
             contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
              usergetNames = data;
             tinyMCE();
             },
           error: function (ex) {
           alert(ex.responseText);
         }
    });
```

In tinyMCE, replace var userNames line with this

```
var userNames = usergetNames;
```

You can get the rest of the code for tinymce mentions in their official documentation page.

Comment: Hello, I've run into this exact problem myself just now. I like your `$.ajax` call that makes sense. but what is the `tinyMCE()` function?

Comment: I wrapped the tinymce init settings in a function called tinyMCE(), then I call it in the ajax success